# Cumulative average by month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date column:

| Date | Hours | Week Status | Month average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/may/2023 | 2 | OK | 2 |
| 2/may/2023 | 0 | OK | 1 |
| (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) |
| 31/dec/2023 | (...) | (...) | (...) |

I want a formula to:

**Month average** = cumulative average for the month until the last day of the month.

I just can't figure it out. Sorry and thanks.

I tried creating helper columns (day of the week, week number and month) so I can write a formula for the whole column, but I just can't figure it out. I also did a google search and chatGPT, got it wrong.

Comment: This can be done without helper columns. Look into [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642). Please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AVERAGEIFS()

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&EOMONTH(A2,-1)+1,A:A,"<="&A2)
```

This will only look at dates in the month/year that are equal to the month/year up to the date in B2.

Put that in D2 and copy/paste down.

Comment: Thanks It worked, now I will try to understand it hehe.